Which IC (26AC19) is located in an FPC Lightning cable or which IC is needed to charge an iPad?
I recently disassembled a Lightning cable to investigate the components hidden under the insulation. Inside, I found a 6-pin IC next to a MOSFET, labeled "26AC19". Unfortunately, I couldn't find any information about this IC online.

My goal is to replicate the functionality of this cable on a custom PCB. Therefore, I need to identify this IC to either transfer it to my PCB or find a source to purchase it separately.
As a first attempt to understand the circuit, I reengineered the connections as shown in the schematic:

Does anyone have any information on this IC or its possible equivalents?

It's a clone of the MFI chip used by certified manufacturers of Lightning cables.
Official part number are something like MFI337S3959, but that will be of little use to you.
You can buy the plug with a small PCB and the cloned MFI components on it, that might be your best bet. Lightning is kind of passé anyway.

Thanks! I know I am riding an old horse, but for a specific use case, I will need like hundred of circuits which will be able to charge an iPad. For the project I will need a similar FPC cable, but without the circuit. Without the circuit the iPad doesn't charge. So I need to recreate the circuit on my PCB. The IC from the 2-Pin FPC cable is very easy to use (Hardware wise) so I would like to stick with it. Any idea how I could proceed?

Personally, I would buy the lightning head with the chip on a small PCB (or a lightning to USB  cable with the chip) from a supplier for such a small quantity. The former cost about 0.11 USD in China, so I'm sure you can find them at an affordable price.

I need an ultra-flat and 90 degree angled Plug. That's why I have researched for this FPC cable. They sell it in two versions. 2 and 3 pin. In both cases it uses GND, Power and ID of the Lightning head. The 2 pin Version has the authentication chip on it and the 3 pin version leaves the ID trace open. Since the elevation of the circuit on the cable is a problem for my use case, I want to take the 3 pin version with the IC on the PCB. Therefore I need the ICs itself.

There are suppliers in China who offer the chip number I've mentioned (QFN8 with pad) and claim it's genuine Apple original, but of course no datasheet type information. I guess you could remove the chips from the board. I have never had much luck tracking down the makers of this kind of gray market chip and the information required to use it, but I've never tried all that hard either. Anyone with large quantities to buy will find a way.

Thanks mate! I will take a look on that
